# google maps v2 to v3: roadmap getTile() why doesn't work?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Why this v2-like construction doesn't work in v3?

(instead roadmap tile path I get undefined)

```
var mytype = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
  getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
    var url = '';
    if (cond_need_custom_tiles) {
      url = 'http://domain.com/mytiles/tile-'+tile.x+'-'+tile.y+'-'+zoom;
    }
    else { // need ROADMAP tiles
      // old (v2):
      // url = G_NORMAL_MAP.getTileLayers()[0].getTileUrl(tile, zoom);

      // new (v3):
      url = map.mapTypes.get(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP).getTile(tile, zoom); // why it doesn't work??
    }
    console.log(url); // undefined!!! why?
    return url;
  },
  tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: Number(opt.zoom),
  name: 'mytiles',
});
```

PS: I want my tiles mapType and ROADMAP in background (where no my tiles), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getTile() is no longer defined for basemaps; it should be used only as a user defined method on custom mapTypes -- please see comment #2 of http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3635#c2 for some additional details.

In your particular use case, perhaps you can simply always load the ROADMAP tiles by default, and then display your custom imageMapType as appropriate depending on cond_need_custom_tiles ?

Alternatively the bug noted above would be a good place to provide additional details on your use case.

Comment: > you can simply always load the ROADMAP tiles by default  

<br/>Can you give a little example of code?